# How to replace html with haml in File.read()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I tried to rewrite one of the process to read Haml file to replace existng working HTML file as following:

This is the existing code in the controller:

```
f= "app/views/newform/.html.erb"
@ui= File.read(f)
```

According to the Haml engine [documentation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Engine.html) I tried to replace it with

```
html_engine = Haml::Engine.new(f)
@ui= html_engine.render
```

and got this result to be only file name:

```
=> "app/views/articles/new_article/form_article.haml\n"
```

instead of (when in HTML)

```
[1] pry(#<JinController>)> @ui
=> "<%\n  article = Article.new\n%>\n<%= fields_for article do |f| %>\n  <%= f.label :title, \"Title\" %>\n  <%= f.text_field :title %>\n
<%= f.label :text, \"Text\" %>\n  <%= f.text_field :text %>\n  <%=
f.label :text, \"Keywords\" %>\n  <%= f.text_field :keywords %>\n  <%=
f.label :body, \"Body Content\" %>\n  <%= f.cktext_area :body %>\n<%
end %>\n"
```

This is the HTML:

```
<%                                                                                                                                    
  article = Article.new                                                                                                               
%>                                                                                                                                    
<%= fields_for article do |f| %>                                                                                                      
  <%= f.label :title, "Title" %>                                                                                                      
  <%= f.text_field :title %>                                                                                                          
  <%= f.label :text, "Text" %>                                                                                                        
  <%= f.text_field :text %>                                                                                                           
  <%= f.label :text, "Keywords" %>                                                                                                    
  <%= f.text_field :keywords %>                                                                                                       
  <%= f.label :body, "Body Content" %>                                                                                                
  <%= f.cktext_area :body %>                                                                                                          
<% end %~
```

And Haml:

```
.container                                                                                                                            
  %div(style="text-align:center")                                                                                                     
    - @title= 'New Article'                                                                                                           
    - article = @article                                                                                                              
    = fields_for article do |f|                                                                                                       
      = f.label :title, "Title"                                                                                                       
      = f.text_field :title                                                                                                           
      = f.label :text, "Description"                                                                                                  
      = f.text_field :text                                                                                                            
      = f.label :text, "Keywords"                                                                                                     
      = f.text_field :keywords                                                                                                        
      = f.label :body, "Body Content"                                                                                                 
      = f.cktext_area :body
```

So how do I replace HTML with Haml in this code?

Comment: Are you missing a `:` here: `Haml:Engine.new(f)`?

Comment: Yes it was, let me try the program again

Answer (score 0):

I might be incorrect but that is for interacting with Haml programmatically not HTML.

From the docs you linked:

> Overview This is the frontend for using Haml programmatically. It can
>   be directly used by the user by creating a new instance and calling
>   #render to render the template. For example:

```
template = File.read('templates/really_cool_template.haml')
haml_engine = Haml::Engine.new(template)
output = haml_engine.render
puts output
```

Notice it is reading Haml there.

I think "[Did you know that HAML and RAILS doing really good together?](https://medium.com/@admatbandara/why-haml-with-rails-7f67fe1af85a)" might help you. The author links to a gem that can convert as well as other options. You just have to scroll down about mid-way through.

He links to [Html2haml](https://github.com/haml/html2haml?source=post_page-----7f67fe1af85a----------------------).

"[Haml and Rails](https://railsapps.github.io/rails-haml.html)" also talks about it.

This is actually from the first article.

You can [convert an html.erb file to Haml](http://%20Convert%20HTML%20to%20HAML).

Comment: Hi Thank, that link is about html to haml. I already in haml but my problem is to refactor existing html file to be haml with others on project. This is only one that still required html and I want to change.

Comment: That gem refactors existing html.erb files to haml in bulk but if you just need a singular file you can just use that website link and copy your view into it and it should turn it into haml that you can just paste back over: http://htmltohaml.com/?source=post_page-----7f67fe1af85a---------------------- Sorry the link I left at the bottom didn't go to a working app! My bad updating the last link in my answer. I just tried on one of my erb files and it works just fine correctly interpreting the ruby too.

Comment: This have to be done in code not copy and paste manually. I will try debug the Haml Engine, I think it's there when I use ls in pry. Thanks anyway.